# Must declare the scalar variable "@metaTags"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry I am not that great with sql I basically mimic the syntax and try to add this new tag into the sql function.

basicly This new metaTags Field is within 3 Tables as [Text] , They will just output the additional value.

```
USE [cert]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_SEO]    Script Date: 06/03/2014 14:55:01 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      VVF Solutions Inc
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SEO]
    @script_name varchar(255), @attorneyId int=0, @practiceAreaId int=0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @DisplayName varchar(50), @metaKey varchar(8000), @metaDesc varchar(8000), @metaTags varchar(8000)

    IF @practiceAreaId != 0
        BEGIN
        SELECT @DisplayName = '', @metaKey = MetaKeywords, @metaDesc = MetaDescription, @metaTags = metaTags
        FROM PracticeAreas 
        WHERE PracticeAreaID = @practiceAreaId
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SELECT @DisplayName = DisplayName, @metaKey = MetaKeywords, @metaDesc = MetaDescription , @metaTags = metaTags
        FROM SEO 
        WHERE Active = 1 and scriptname = @script_name
        END



    IF @attorneyId != 0
        BEGIN
        SELECT @DisplayName = '', @metaKey = MetaKeywords, @metaDesc = MetaDescription , @metaTags = metaTags
        FROM Attorneys 
        WHERE AttorneyID = @attorneyId
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SELECT @DisplayName = DisplayName, @metaKey = MetaKeywords, @metaDesc = MetaDescription , @metaTags = metaTags
        FROM SEO 
        WHERE Active = 1 and scriptname = @script_name
        END

    if ( (LEN(@metaKey) < 2 AND LEN(@metaDesc) < 2) OR (@metaKey is null and @metaDesc is null) )
    BEGIN
        SELECT @metaKey = MetaKeywords, @metaDesc = MetaDescription, @metaTags = metaTags
        FROM SEO 
        WHERE Id = 0
    END

    if (@DisplayName is not null and len(@DisplayName) > 2)
        set @DisplayName = ' | ' + @DisplayName

    select @DisplayName as DisplayName, @metaKey as metakeywords, @metaDesc as metadescription, @metaTags as metaTags
END
```

This function **still returns the OLD values** but not the new one (i am guessing it is because of the error)

[image]

Comment: When do you get this error. When running Alter Procedure or when executing procedure?

Comment: @Horaciux I clicked the "! Execute" in SQL Management studio, But this time (without Edits) command(s) completed Successfully it returned. BUT the problem still exist as It **does not Return** the value inside metaTags (I opened the already edited procedure to debug the problem, so alter procedure)

Comment: @Horaciux It said the error in Title "Must declare the scalar variable “@metaTags”" See my edits for new sceenshot

Comment: what type is metaTag columns in each table?

Comment: found my logic error on "SELECT metaKey = MetaKeywords, metaDesc = MetaDescription, metaTags = metaTags"

Comment: Good for you!. Anyway, you must concider to change TEXT filds for VARCHAR(MAX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out I just have a logic error.

```
if ( (LEN(@metaKey) < 2 AND LEN(@metaDesc) < 2) OR (@metaKey is null and @metaDesc is null) )
    BEGIN
        SELECT @metaKey = MetaKeywords, @metaDesc = MetaDescription, @metaTags = metaTags
        FROM SEO 
        WHERE Id = 0
    END
```

removed the overwrite and it worked as it should